# How to use deferred objects to wait until AJAX is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred

**Workflow:**

With the macro goal of not having the user wait for anything, this is the user-flow of what I'm trying to do:

1. User fills out form
2. User clicks button to submit form
3. Form submits async via AJAX (FWIW, processing takes ~5 seconds)
4. Immediately after the form is async submitted, jQuery pops up a survey modal
5. User can either fill out survey and click button to submit it, or click button to skip it entirely

What I'm having trouble accomplishing now is the effect after user clicks `submit-survey` or `skip-survey`. It's easiest to talk about skipping first. If the user chooses to skip the survey, then this happens:

1. A "working" overlay appears over the page for as long as the async needs to still finish (if at all needed), because once the async finishes, it returns the right next action that needs to happen in the jQuery code (for example purposes, let's say this is a simple `console.log`)

If the user fills out the survey and clicks `submit-survey`, then what happens is this:

1. Survey submits async via AJAX
2. A "working" overlay appears over the page for as long as the async needs to still finish (exactly same as if `skip-survey` were clicked)

The additional complexity is that, the survey submits to a different route depending on if the first form is completed by the time the user clicks the `submit-survey`

**Code**

I'm taking this opportunity to learn more about async flows in general, which is why the code is a mess. Right now the implementation I'm thinking is that the form submission AJAX, once it's succeeded or failed, generates the 1) appropriate URL for survey submission and the 2) next action that submit or survey will ultimately trigger)

So something like...

```
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url :  '/orders/create_or_update',
  dataType: 'json', 
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data : JSON.stringify(params)
})
.done(function(){
  // submit-survey post route
  submit-url = '/orders/success_ajax_update'
  // next action triggered by skip-survey and submit-survey
  function nextAction() { console.log("fail") }
})
.fail(function(){
  // submit-survey post route
  submit-url = '/almost_orders/fail_ajax_update'
  // next action triggered by skip-survey and submit-survey
  function nextAction() { console.log("fail") }
})

$(document).on("click", "#submit-survey", function() {
  if (isFunction(nextAction)) {
    $.ajax({url: submit-url, ... })
    nextAction()
  } else {
    addWorkingOverlay();
  }
})

$(document).on("click", "#skip-survey", function() {
  if (isFunction(nextAction)) {
    nextAction()
  } else {
    addWorkingOverlay();
  }
})
```

The problem with the above though, is if user clicks either `submit-survey` or `skip-survey` before the AJAX has finished, then the working overlay gets added, but nothing then says "oh now AJAX has finished, nextAction is defined, so loop again". And obviously I can add a counter to check back on `isFunction(nextAction)` but this seems to completely defeat the purpose of AJAX in the first place.

Ideas on how to fix this?

Have new idea, need more help to flesh out. Per documentation, you can use jQuery's `.when` like so:

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) )
  .then( myFunc, myFailure );
```

This can work in my case, only instead of a second `.ajax` I have a button click (either submit or skip). The question with this idea becomes, how do I turn the user's click of either submit or skip button into a resolved deferred that the `.when` can work with?

Comment: You only declaring a function inside the promise `done` callback - It's not available outside the `done` scope, so why not just setting the button to be disabled by default, and enable it when the ajax finishes (in the `done` part)?

Comment: that's a little less user-friendly, basically i want the user to always be able to click ahead. in the workflow above, the user is only forcefully stopped if s/he skips or submits the survey too fast. but otherwise it's going straight through

Comment: and yes the declaration point is well made. `submit-url` i can initialize as a global variable. `nextAction`... more complicated

Comment: So make a global variable (`var nextAction;` before the `$.ajax({..`) and inside the `done` callback change the current function to `nextAction = function() { console.log("fail") };`, this way you're using a variable and assigning it a function, which is avalable also inside the click event

Comment: I would add the working overlay as part of submitting the original form. Then display the survey over this. Then regardless of what the user does with the survey, the working overlay appears, and disappears when the original AJAX finishes.

Comment: @AlonEitan @Barmar both very good ideas, thanks! Will implement. Any thoughts though on how to ... wait-until-done on the `submit-survey` and `click-survey` part?

Comment: This question looks very familiar. Was it not asked about 10 days ago, then withdrawn?

Comment: @roamer-1888 not by me...